# How much stack space is typically reserved for a thread? (POSIX / OSX)

Tags: multithreading, macos, assembly, operating-system, posix

The answer probably differs depending on the OS, but I'm curious how much stack space does a thread normally preallocate. For example, if I use:

```
push rax
```

that will put a value on the stack and increment the `rsp`. But what if I never use a `push` op? I imagine some space still gets allocated, but how much? Also, is this a fixed amount or is does it grow dynamically with the amount of stuff `push`ed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX does not define any standards regarding stack size, it is entirely implementation dependent.  Since you tagged this `OSX`, the default allocations there are :

- Main thread (8MB)
- Secondary Thread (512kB)

Naturally, these can be configured to suit your needs.  The allocation is dynamic :

> The minimum allowed stack size for secondary threads is 16 KB and the
>   stack size must be a multiple of 4 KB. The space for this memory is
>   set aside in your process space at thread creation time, but ***the
>   actual pages associated with that memory are not created until they
>   are needed***.

There is too much detail to include here.  I suggest you read :

[Thread Management (Mac Developer Library)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)